# Filter questions by excluding tags

Tags: support, tags, search

Please forgive me if this question is already answered. I am looking for a way to search for some questions by excluding some tags.

Example:
I am a Java programmer and I am usually using the java tag to search for relevant questions to answer. The problem is that the search results are full of Android questions! I would like to filter for Java questions non-related with Android.
I have tried [java][!android] but it didn't work. Is there a way or is an improvement?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try this one,
It will display all newest questions with java tag excluding questions with android tag.

[`[java] -[android]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java+-android?sort=newest&pageSize=50)

You can also set this in your preferences, steps are...

> Profile -> Preferences -> Ignored tags -> Hide questions in your
>   ignored tags

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked! I will accept your answer as soon as I can :)